# PHP - $_SESSION contains data, but is still NULL

Tags: php, session, pdo

I have a problem with my $_SESSION variable in PHP.

When I check what the session contains, this is the information I get:

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

gives me:

```
array(7) { ["hash"]=> string(26) "5523F85C0EC9F5523F85C0ECD9" ["numbersValue"]=> int(8) ["user"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(5) "31871" ["username"]=> string(5) "Admin" ["logkey"]=> string(32) "b26e828f52844cb5ee2db5ce99470ee8" } ["addons"]=> array(0) { } ["load_plugins"]=> array(0) { } ["language"]=> string(7) "english" ["fb_Your Facebook App ID_state"]=> string(32) "ea6fffc683328ffb04324d0e27a7476d" }
```

Although when I try to use a variable from the `$_SESSION`, like `$_SESSION["username"];` which should say "Admin", all I get is NULL:

```
var_dump($_SESSION["username"]);
```

gives me:

```
NULL
```

This is the structure:

- **Index.php:** `session_start();` is called here. `Core.php` is included here also.
- **connect.php:** Is where I wish to use the `$_SESSION` data - and it is also in this file I tried to var_dump the session to see what data it contains.

Why can't I use `$_SESSION["DATA"]` in my script?

Comment: just looking at your var_dump above, username is inside of a user array. So $_SESSION['user']['username'] would have that username.

Comment: oh dear! 3 answers and a comment all saying the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not accessing your variables correctly:

```
var_dump($_SESSION["username"]);
```

As you can see in the `var_dump` of the session, you have a nested array, so you would need for this specific variable:

```
var_dump($_SESSION['user']["username"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`username` is in the `user` array:

```
$_SESSION['user']['username']
```

You might use something like this to see the structure:

```
highlight_string(var_export($_SESSION, true));
```